# Summing a Dynamic Range based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(Pictures included) -
I'm trying to write a formula that sums the Forecast Qty (dynamic range) based on multiple criteria. The criteria I want to base it on is the Part number and the month (Aug-21, Sep-21 etc). Each part can have multiple forecasts for each month, I've ran a match formula that shows the first row in which each part changes, but am not sure how to necessarily break it down further into months.

[image: Column A excluded for Privacy. Raw data]

[image: Desired format]

The previous pictures will give more insight into what I want. The first picture shows my raw data and the Match function I performed to find the first row of corresponding part. The second picture shows where I'd like the end result. The '100' in the selected cell is the result of the formula I have ran below.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(F2,HIghJump!B:F,4,FALSE)>DATEVALUE("9/01/2021"),SUM(HIghJump!F2:F6))
```

My issue is how do I get the range in the sum formula (F2:F6), to change based on corresponding month. Beyond that, how do I get this formula to change based on different parts and different numbers of forecasts per month.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ScottCraner , thanks for the response. I've tried to use SUMIFS but I'm really struggling with the logic and syntax. Is there anyway you could walk me through it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
Had to create a column using MONTH(x), then base SUMIFS off that vs the original month column.

```
=SUMIFS(HIghJump!F:F,HIghJump!H:H,MONTH(K$1),HIghJump!B:B,F2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(HIghJump!$F:$F,HIghJump!$B:$B,$F2,HIghJump!$E:$E,">="&EOMONTH(K$1,-1)+1,HIghJump!$E:$E,"<"&EOMONTH(K$1,0)+1)
```

This should go in L2 and copy down.  Change the `K$1` to each corresponding target date when moving over columns.

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for the response. Ran this and I'm not getting the expected results. Could you walk me through your logic?

Comment: first criterion is the sum field, the second matches column B with F2 and then we use K1 as the date reference and book end column E on the first and last day of the month.  I had a typo and had K2, it should be K1.  See edit.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm not getting the expected 100, 644, 570 etc, instead I'm getting all 0's.

Comment: it appears your forcast_qty are numbers stored as text and as such text will not sum.

Comment: Okay, changed the data type to Number now and still no luck. Any further input?

Comment: Changing the format will not change the type.  If the type is text changing the format will do nothing it will remain as text.  You will need to convert them to numbers, there are many tutorials on how to do that around. @dugoutaz

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild The beauty of SUMIFS is that it does not care if the dates are stored as text or real dates.  If they can be converted to dates then using them in the criteria will work whether they are text or true dates.  The only thing it will not do is convert numbers stored as text in the sum column.

Comment: Scott, I've converted the text to numbers with text to columns and the value function. Still just returning 0's.

Comment: I also don't have the green tick in the forecast column. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: At this point I can no longer guess as to the problem.  One thing to check, what is the value shown in K1 in the formula bar?

Comment: 8/1/2021 , tried converting it to a date specific, was already I believe

Comment: Scott, would it be worth posting again with the current formula? Would there be anyway I could get the file to you so you could have a closer look? No worries if that's too much, just trying to figure this out cause my boss wants at the end of the day.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not accept files from unknown sources.  And asking a new question will probably just garner the same questions I am asking.  You can minimize the tables to a small test group that demonstrates the problem and ask a new question.  That is what we call a [mcve].  Do not just take photos of your large table.  Create smaller tables and use that in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help scott, your formula set me in the right direction. I ended up having to create a new column that used the MONTH function get me a numeric month number. Then I used this function to get me the desired output.  `=SUMIFS(HIghJump!F:F,HIghJump!H:H,MONTH(K$1),HIghJump!B:B,F2)`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly and if you have the newest version of Excel, then `FILTER` will come in handy.

Try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(HIghJump!F:F, 
(HIghJump!B:B=$F2)*(HIghJump!B:B>=K$1)*(HIghJump!B:B<EOMONTH(K$1,0)+1))
```

Note that it is generally considered best practice to use partial ranges (e.g. $B$1:$F$100 and $B$1:$B$100 instead of B:F and B:B), so that might be something you would want to consider if performance is of importance to you. Also make sure your sheet name is really "HIghJump" instead of "High Jump" or some variation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It seems that I don't have the FILTER function.